# Error installing Apache on Linux

Tags: debian, software-installation, apache-httpd, dpkg

I´m trying to install apache2 on my Linux VM but it returns me an error and I don´t know how to fix it. I used the command:

```
sudo apt install apache2
```

This is the errors that returns me:

```
update-alternatives: error: unable to read link `/etc/alternatives/rename': Invalid argument
dpkg: error processing package perl (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libdbi-perl:
 libdbi-perl depends on perl (>= 5.18.1-4build1); however:
  Package perl is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libdbi-perl (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libdbd-mysql-perl:
 libdbd-mysql-perl depends on perl (>= 5.18.2-2ubuntu1.1); however:
  Package perl is not configured yet.
 libdbd-mysql-perl depends on perl-dbdabi-94; however:
  Package perl-dbdabi-94 is not installed.
  Package libdbi-perl which provides perl-dbdabi-94 is not configured yet.
 libdbd-mysql-perl depends on libdbi-perl; however:
  Package libdbi-perl is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libdbd-mysql-perl (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-client-5.5:
 mysql-client-5.5 depends on libdbd-mysql-perl (>= 1.2202); however:
  Package libdbd-mysql-perl is not configured yeNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                        t.
 mysql-client-5.5 depends on libdbi-perl; however:
  Package libdbi-perl is not configured yet.
 mysql-client-5.5 depends on perl; however:
  Package perl is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-client-5.5 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server-5.5:
 mysql-server-5.5 depends on libdbi-perl; however:
  Package libdbi-perl is not configured yet.
 mysql-server-5.5 depends on mysql-client-5.5 (>= 5.5.60-0ubuntu0.14.04.1); however:
  Package mysql-client-5.5 is not configured yet.
 mysql-server-5.5 depends on perl (>= 5.6); however:
  Package perl is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up procps (1:3.3.9-1ubuntu2.3) ...
update-alternatives: error: unable to read link `/etc/alternatives/w': Invalid argument
dpkg: error processing package procps (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up openssh-client (1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.10) ...
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              update-alternatives: error: unable to read link `/etc/alternatives/rlogin': Invalid argument
dpkg: error processing package openssh-client (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text (0.8.8-0ubuntu17.2) ...No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

update-alternatives: error: unable to read link `/etc/alternatives/text.plymouth': Invalid argument
dpkg: error processing package plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apache2-bin:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 apache2-bin depends on perl; however:
  Package perl is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package apache2-bin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apache2:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 apache2 depends on procps; however:
  Package procps is not configured yet.
 apache2 depends on perl; however:
  Package perl is not configured yet.
 apache2 depends on apache2-bin (= 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.20); however:
  Package apache2-bin is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package apache2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apport-gtk:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 apport-gtk depends on procps; however:
  Package procps is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package apport-gtk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libdpkg-perl:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 libdpkg-perl depends on perl; however:
  Package perl is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libdpkg-perl (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dpkg-dev:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 dpkg-dev depends on libdpkg-perl (= 1.17.5ubuntu5.8); however:
  Package libdpkg-perl is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package dpkg-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libarchive-zip-perl:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 libarchive-zip-perl depends on perl; however:
  Package perl is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libarchive-zip-perl (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libhtml-template-perl:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 libhtml-template-perl depends on perl; however:
  Package perl is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libhtml-template-perl (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libxml-libxml-perl:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 libxml-libxml-perl depends on perl (>= 5.18.2-2ubuntu1.3); however:
  Package perl is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libxml-libxml-perl (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-client:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 mysql-client depends on mysql-client-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-client-5.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-client (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openssh-sftp-server:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 openssh-sftp-server depends on openssh-client; however:
  Package openssh-client is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package openssh-sftp-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openssh-server:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 openssh-server depends on openssh-client (= 1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.10); however:
  Package openssh-client is not configured yet.
 openssh-server depends on procps; however:
  Package procps is not configured yet.
 openssh-server depends on openssh-sftp-server; however:
  Package openssh-sftp-server is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package openssh-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up w3m (0.5.3-15ubuntu0.2) ...No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

update-alternatives: error: unable to read link `/etc/alternatives/pager': Invalid argument
dpkg: error processing package w3m (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Errors were encountered while processing:
 perl
 libdbi-perl
 libdbd-mysql-perl
 mysql-client-5.5
 mysql-server-5.5
 procps
 openssh-client
 plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text
 apache2-bin
 apport-gtk
 libdpkg-perl
 dpkg-dev
 libarchive-zip-perl
 libhtml-template-perl
 libxml-libxml-perl
 mysql-client
 mysql-server
 openssh-sftp-server
 openssh-server
 w3m
 apache2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried everything but nothing works

Comment: Show the errors.

Comment: Specifically, _all_ of them.

Comment: Ok. I put all the output of the errors

Comment: Sounds eerily similar to your issue - https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2351730. Even has @steeldriver commenting in this forums post to boot.

Comment: More of the same - https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/update-alternatives-error-unable-to-read-link-%60-etc-alternatives-editor%27-invalid-a-4175488094/. I think you want to delete whatever's going on in your /etc/alternatives directory from the error msg you're getting. Sounds like it's hosed.